# Uniqueness in nested list to have no more than one overlapping pair of coordinates

Tags: python, nested-lists

So I've gone through a whole bunch of circles, detecting where they overlap [like this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7172/how-do-i-find-the-intersections-between-colliding-circles), and now I've plotted the circles that overlap.

But in the corner, as I've shown with the arrow, I have *two* red circles overlapping one blue, but there should only be one overlap detected. The second circle overlapping should be disregarded, based on distance.

How can I remove the extra overlap, so that one red will always overlap one blue, but also the other way around?

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

# Format is (x1, y1, r1), x2, y2, r2), squared_distance)
circles = (((87, 319, 10), (82, 316, 10), 34),
           ((162, 230, 10), (157, 226, 10), 41),
           ((162, 438, 10), (162, 440, 10), 4),
           ((235, 146, 10), (230, 150, 10), 41),
           ((260, 183, 10), (260, 185, 10), 4),
           ((260, 265, 10), (253, 269, 10), 65),
           ((360, 88, 10), (366, 91, 10), 45),
           ((428, 442, 10), (433, 447, 10), 50), # Two red overlap the same blue
           ((438, 453, 10), (433, 447, 10), 61), # So this one (furthest away) must go
           ((459, 24, 10), (465, 21, 10), 45))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (6,6))

ax.set_xlim(0,500)
ax.set_ylim(0,500)

for red, blue, squared_dist in circles:
    x1, y1, r1 = red
    x2, y2, r2 = blue

    c = plt.Circle((x1, y1), r1, color = "red", linewidth = 2, fill = False, alpha = 1)
    ax.add_patch(c)

    c = plt.Circle((x2, y2), r2, color = "blue", linewidth = 2, fill = False, alpha = 1)
    ax.add_patch(c)

ax.arrow(390, 400, 20, 20, head_width=10, head_length=10, fc='k', ec='k')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I solved the problem using Pandas. Turns out that a nested list like the above is actually very easy to work with as a container.

Taking the original circles and making them to a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(circles, columns = ["red", "blue", "dist"])
```

Gives

```
              red            blue  dist
0   (87, 319, 10)   (82, 316, 10)    34
1  (162, 230, 10)  (157, 226, 10)    41
2  (162, 438, 10)  (162, 440, 10)     4
3  (235, 146, 10)  (230, 150, 10)    41
4  (260, 183, 10)  (260, 185, 10)     4
5  (260, 265, 10)  (253, 269, 10)    65
6   (360, 88, 10)   (366, 91, 10)    45
7  (428, 442, 10)  (433, 447, 10)    50 
8  (438, 453, 10)  (433, 447, 10)    61 
9   (459, 24, 10)   (465, 21, 10)    45
```

And then, simply dropping duplicates will work, if sorted by distance.

```
df = df.sort_values("dist").drop_duplicates("red").drop_duplicates("blue").reset_index(drop = True)
```

Yielding

```
              red            blue  dist
0   (87, 319, 10)   (82, 316, 10)    34
1  (162, 230, 10)  (157, 226, 10)    41
2  (162, 438, 10)  (162, 440, 10)     4
3  (235, 146, 10)  (230, 150, 10)    41
4  (260, 183, 10)  (260, 185, 10)     4
5  (260, 265, 10)  (253, 269, 10)    65
6   (360, 88, 10)   (366, 91, 10)    45
7  (428, 442, 10)  (433, 447, 10)    50
9   (459, 24, 10)   (465, 21, 10)    45
```

And row 8 is removed.